# Some cat ate The Whiteboard; Chat has broke

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

It would appear as though The Whiteboard has been swallowed whole like an egg roll by this cat:

[image]

Help?

Comment: Seems to work fine to me as of 11:10am EDT.

Comment: If there's a cat involved, it's probably Anna Lear's fault.

Comment: @YannisRizos ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be back to working now; see [Chat.SE is down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175161/chat-se-is-down) on Meta Stack Overflow.